# AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to follow a basic AWS tutorial for interacting with DynamoDB in a java runtime environment on a AWS serverless setup. However, for some reason eclipse is throwing an error when I try to create a new AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder

I  double-checked and I see the proper dependencies documented in POM.xml, however I still keep getting the error "AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard cannot be resolved to a type"

The code:

```
package com.serverless.demo.function;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;


public class HelloWorld implements RequestHandler<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {

        AmazonDynamoDB client = new AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Can you post your maven.xml?

You should have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.163</version>
</dependency>
```

Check for the latest version of the archive on mvnrepository [[here]](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb).

Or alternatively a maven file structured as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.166</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Please note:**

This answer was given when there wasn't a 2nd version of the AWS SDK.  In AWS SDK v2 your classes are prefixed with `software.amazon.awssdk`. They no longer reside in packages prefixed with `com.amazonaws` as in AWS SDK v1.

Using AWS SDK v2 you can setup your Maven BOM (bill of materials) as follows:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.78</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

For the AWS documentation on setting up a Maven project check [[here]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html). For the latest version of the AWS BOM check [[here]](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/bom).

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem in my case. But they could mention it in the documentation from amazonaws, I think. Hadn't so much trouble if they would.

Comment: Hey, I have added aws-java-sdk-dynamodb to my pom but after uploading the jar and testing I get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" - I am using scope->provided to reduce the size of jar

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to not specify `new`, because the `standard()` method performs the instantiation for you:

`AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().build();`

Answer (score 0):

Just having the following dependency is not enough

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.456</version>
</dependency>
```

you also need to add a classpath entry to the .classpath file (edit the path by replacing USERNAME and making other necessary edits)

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.456/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.456.jar" sourcepath="C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.456/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.456-sources.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:file:/C:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.456/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.456-javadoc.jar!/"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        <attribute name="maven.groupId" value="com.amazonaws"/>
        <attribute name="maven.artifactId" value="aws-java-sdk-dynamodb"/>
        <attribute name="maven.version" value="1.11.456"/>
        <attribute name="maven.scope" value="provided"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

You shold also check for the latest dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb) 
Hope this helps!